# How can I monitor CPU usage by user?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, cpu

I need to monitor CPU usage by users of two servers' (Ubuntu and CentOS). For example:

```
user1     5%
user2    10%
...
```

Is there a tool similar to `top` or `htop` that can do that?

Comment: Do you need top to be displayed in real time? Otherwise, you could consider `top -u user` and redirect the result to a file, and then monitor another user. you would then have a monitor of proc usage for your users at a given interval.

Comment: When you say monitor over what period? Once in a while or continuously?

Comment: I'm hoping to be able to monitor users in realtime like top.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is a script to print the *total* CPU usage for each user *currently logged in*, [showPerUserCPU.sh](https://github.com/scaidermern/script-snippets/blob/master/showPerUserCPU.sh):

```
own=$(id -nu)
cpus=$(lscpu | grep "^CPU(s):" | awk '{print $2}')

for user in $(who | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u)
do
    # print other user's CPU usage in parallel but skip own one because
    # spawning many processes will increase our CPU usage significantly
    if [ "$user" = "$own" ]; then continue; fi
    (top -b -n 1 -u "$user" | awk -v user=$user -v CPUS=$cpus 'NR>7 { sum += $9; } END { print user, sum, sum/CPUS; }') &
    # don't spawn too many processes in parallel
    sleep 0.05
done
wait

# print own CPU usage after all spawned processes completed
top -b -n 1 -u "$own" | awk -v user=$own -v CPUS=$cpus 'NR>7 { sum += $9; } END { print user, sum, sum/CPUS; }'
```

And here is a slightly modified version for printing the CPU usage of *all* available users (but skipping the ones with a CPU usage of zero), [showAllPerUserCPU.sh](https://github.com/scaidermern/script-snippets/blob/master/showAllPerUserCPU.sh):

```
own=$(id -nu)
cpus=$(lscpu | grep "^CPU(s):" | awk '{print $2}')

for user in $(getent passwd | awk -F ":" '{print $1}' | sort -u)
do
    # print other user's CPU usage in parallel but skip own one because
    # spawning many processes will increase our CPU usage significantly
    if [ "$user" = "$own" ]; then continue; fi
    (top -b -n 1 -u "$user" | awk -v user=$user -v CPUS=$cpus 'NR>7 { sum += $9; } END { if (sum > 0.0) print user, sum, sum/CPUS; }') &
    # don't spawn too many processes in parallel
    sleep 0.05
done
wait

# print own CPU usage after all spawned processes completed
top -b -n 1 -u "$own" | awk -v user=$own -v CPUS=$cpus 'NR>7 { sum += $9; } END { print user, sum, sum/CPUS; }'
```

The first column represents the user name, the second column the aggregated CPU usage and the third column the normalized CPU use according to the number of CPU cores.

There is also a related script for showing the *total* memory usage for each user: [showPerUserMem.sh](https://github.com/scaidermern/script-snippets/blob/master/showPerUserMem.sh)

For live-monitoring just execute these scripts periodically via the `watch` command.

For sorting by CPU usage, pipe the output to `sort -k2 -nr`.

Comment: why you are mixing bash env variable with script variable means $USER already exists, even all caps variable is env isn't it?

Comment: I don't think that all uppercase variables must be environment variables. But I agree that overwriting already existing variables is not a very nice style.

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to use UPPERCASE in bash, for the reason that Rahul mentioned. It is even worse when you are using a variable name that _already_ exists as an environmental one (n bash, `$USER` is your username already, so ut's the same as the `id -nu` command you are using. I've edited your post to change this.

Comment: Using uppercase variables in shell scripts is surely not a bad idea as nine out of ten scripts in my `/etc/init.d/` directory are doing this, too. Overwriting existing environment variables in contrast should be avoided.

Comment: Could I make it show CPU usage of all the users in the system?

Comment: I added a version to include *every* user, not just the ones currently logged in.