# get cpu by user

Tags: process, monitoring, top

Working with monit I need create an alert that get cpu usage of system users, so:

```
top -b -n 1 -u user1 | awk 'NR>7 { sum += $9; } END { print sum; }'
```

seems a good solution but I'm not sure about reliable because when I do above command, every time change (obviously) the value. So, I need an "exact" use of cpu by user within 2-5 seconds, because the VALUE will send like an email alert.

Comment: You can check this question. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120570/how-can-i-monitor-cpu-usage-by-user

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args | sort -k 1 -r | head -5
```

Output will be like

```
%CPU   PID USER     COMMAND
0.6 18695 mysql  /usr/sbin/mysqld
0.1   961 root     [kdmflush]
0.1   937 root     [kdmflush]
0.1  1025 root     [jbd2/dm-2-8]
```

Comment: How can this be modified to get CPU usage of a single user